# c++ server design boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, server, asio

I am skeptic at my current design of my gameserver, and am seeking for actual guidance.
I am currently preallocating a fixed number of clients, with their own receive buffers in the class, preallocated.
All good, until i meet a point where at handling packets, i need to answer back.
My current design is preallocating a fixed number of sendbuffers, and taking one out of the freelist in a lockless way, and putting it back once the packet is sent.
I would like to know if the correct way is to use a lockless free buffer list, or i need to call new/delete on each time i am sending a new packet.

The current way:

```
T_SendBufferTCP* CServer::GetFreeSendBuffer()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SEND_BUFFER_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (__sync_val_compare_and_swap(&pSendBuffers[i]->iOwnedCount, 0, 1) == 0)
        {
            return pSendBuffers[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("No Free SendBuffers.\r\n");
    exit(0);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: A few things to nitpick at unrelated to your question: First I would rather use the standard [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) class instead of the non-portable function you have now, more specifically a `std::atomit<bool>`. Then you seem to misunderstand what `return` and `exit` does. The `return` statement have the function return *immediately*, no statements after it will run. Same with `exit`, it exits the process immediately, and will not even return. Using `exit` might be a bad choice of error-handling for a server.

Comment: Thanks for the atomic tip. the exit is for force closing the server, cause i the gameserver cannot proceed usual tasks if theres no send buffers available, which means a bug on my end, it should never happen.